# variable lifecycle in anonymous functions golang

Tags: go, anonymous-function

im sorry if my question may has obvious or easy answer but i really cant undesrstand what is going on.
this is my code:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := test()
    a()
    a()
}

func test() func() {
    num := 0
    fmt.Println("num in test function", num)
    return func() {
        fmt.Println("num in anonymous function", num)
        num++
        fmt.Printf("square is %v: \n", num*num)
        fmt.Println("=====---====")
    }
}
```

and this is my output:

num in test function 0
num in anonymous function 0
square is 1:
=====---====
num in anonymous function 1
square is 4:
=====---====`

first why `println` num in test function execute just one time while i execute `a()` twice?
and why num in the anonymous function doesnt reset to zero while the num in parent scope is zero?

Comment: Why would `test` be called again when you call `a` (the inner anonymous function)?

Comment: The `fmt.Println` in `test()` is called once because you used it just once in `a := test()`. It does not have to do anything with the inner anonymous function (since it is not a part of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `a := test()` you initialize `num` variable inside `a` anonymous fonction and print `num in test function 0`.

Then, `a` is only the result of your `test()` method, so you will not call your first print when you execute `a()`.
On the same way, `num := 0` is not called anymore. So the local variable `num` assigned inside `a` will just be incremented on each call of `a()`.